# How to I add this image in a button in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image

here this is the code for the button.

`<%= submit_tag 'Find', class: 'btn btn-find', name: nil %>`

This is the image i want to put in.

`<%= image_tag 'star.svg', class: "imgstar" %>`

Comment: @PardeepDhingra That's not the same thing at all, what if he's trying to submit a form?

Comment: @meagar if you will open the link yagooar has mentioned solution with submit tag too.

Comment: @PardeepDhingra that's fine, I'm talking about two of your three comments here, specifically "Why don't you use a link instead" and a demonstration of using `link_to`. Further, even though an answer posted in the other question might also answer this question, the **questions** are not duplicates.

Comment: Okay.. though we can submit form using jquery too.

Comment: @PardeepDhingra That's a bad argument. Just because we *can* use jQuery to solve a problem doesn't mean we *should*. In this case, using jQuery or JavaScript is **completely wrong**. There is absolutely no reason to layer JavaScript click handlers and form submission code on top of a form just so we can use a link instead of a `<submit>`.

Comment: @meagar i will avoid that in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a dedicated Rails method for this:

```
image_submit_tag("star.svg", class: "btn btn-find")
```

See relevant [Rails docs here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-image_submit_tag).

Answer (score 0):

You can use css to place the image as the background of the button.

```
.imgstar{ background:url(star.svg); }
```